# Magsafe 2 45W (A1436) resistor and capacitor value identification

Tags: magsafe

I was trying to replace the charging wire for MagSafe 2 but I accidentally short the circuit which cause 3 resistors and 1 capacitor  burned.

According to the number recognizable, I guess the biggest resistor is 0.27 Ω(R270).
the second big one is 200 Ω(2000), the smallest one not quite sure but it looks like "4R7" to me, if yes, then it is 4.7 Ω.

The problem is the capacitor, it has exploded, and I am unable to get the reading, does anyone know the value of the capacitor?

[image: PCB overview]
[image: Closeup of components in-situ]
[image: Closeup of individual components]

Comment: I’ve been looking for the schematics for this forever and haven’t had any luck.  +1. That said, I found it cheaper (time and effort) to just get a replacement on eBay.  Just got an 85W (genuine) for $15 including shipping.  I removed the MS cable (from dead unit) and sold it for $7.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Allan. I totally agree your suggestion, actually I purchased another used adapter already. The reason why I posted this here was because I felt it is a waste if just throw it away. So just trying to know if someone has the answer I am looking for.

Comment: I totally agree with the waste aspect.  I really like Apple products, but this “everything’s disposable” attitude they have is something I can’t get on board with.

Comment: You can hand in any Apple-branded cable for recycling at any Apple Store.